# Do we need to wrap app.get in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've come across this code

```
(async () => {
  app.get('/health', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send();
  });
  more endpoints here
  ....

})();
```

I don't get why we need to wrap app.get in async here, is that necessary?

Comment: that's not necessary if you want to use `async/await` instead of promises though, you gotta wrap it.

Comment: @StackedQ - But even then, this code is just setting up endpoints, no need for `await` when doing that.... Still, that's the only reason I can think of they might have done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, but we'd need more context to be sure. As shown, no, there's no point.

It may be that they were relying on information they only got asynchronously for setting up the routes and wanted to use `await` rather than `.then`/`.catch` when using that information, e.g.:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        app.get('/health', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
            res.send();
        });

        const moreRoutes = await getMoreRoutes();
        // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^

        for (const route of moreRoutes) {
            // ...set up more routes
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle/report error
    }
})();
```

If so, hopefully they have a `try`/`catch` around the entire body (as shown above) or a `.catch` at the end like this:

```
(async () => {
    app.get('/health', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.send();
    });

    const moreRoutes = await getMoreRoutes();
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^

    for (const route of moreRoutes) {
        // ...set up more routes
    }
})().catch(e =>  {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

`async`/`await` can make it much easier (IMHO) to read code. But the above can be done with `.then`/`.catch` as well:

```
app.get('/health', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send();
});

getMoreRoutes()
.then(moreRoutes => {
    // ...set up more routes
})
.catch(e =>  {
    // Handle/report error
});
```